# `git log` is stuck in an endless loop

Tags: git, git-log

I am working on a medium sized project with about 20 developers. This morning when I did a `git log`, I got the output below.

Git version: 2.34.1.

Running `git gc` actually finishes relatively quickly.

```
08:52 $ git log
remote: Enumerating objects: 311738, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (311738/311738), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (77161/77161), done.
remote: Total 311738 (delta 227905), reused 310146 (delta 226866), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (311738/311738), 36.77 MiB | 670.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (227905/227905), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 317694, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (317694/317694), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (78474/78474), done.
remote: Total 317694 (delta 232557), reused 316069 (delta 231435), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (317694/317694), 37.42 MiB | 478.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (232557/232557), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 317164, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (317164/317164), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (78354/78354), done.
remote: Total 317164 (delta 232161), reused 315513 (delta 231028), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (317164/317164), 37.35 MiB | 606.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (232161/232161), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 276567, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (276567/276567), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67999/67999), done.
remote: Total 276567 (delta 201960), reused 276032 (delta 201836), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (276567/276567), 32.36 MiB | 635.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (201960/201960), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 304543, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (304543/304543), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (75375/75375), done.
remote: Total 304543 (delta 222397), reused 303208 (delta 221598), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (304543/304543), 35.92 MiB | 497.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (222397/222397), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 288743, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (288743/288743), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71242/71242), done.
remote: Total 288743 (delta 210649), reused 287898 (delta 210318), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (288743/288743), 34.01 MiB | 948.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (210649/210649), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 276619, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (276619/276619), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67966/67966), done.
remote: Total 276619 (delta 202009), reused 276117 (delta 201918), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (276619/276619), 32.38 MiB | 539.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (202009/202009), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 233815, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (233815/233815), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58012/58012), done.
remote: Total 233815 (delta 170084), reused 233375 (delta 169985), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (233815/233815), 27.23 MiB | 688.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (170084/170084), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 311355, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (311355/311355), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (77049/77049), done.
remote: Total 311355 (delta 227572), reused 309853 (delta 226593), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (311355/311355), 36.76 MiB | 662.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (227572/227572), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 220996, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (220996/220996), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55149/55149), done.
remote: Total 220996 (delta 160459), reused 220703 (delta 160425), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (220996/220996), 25.57 MiB | 957.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (160459/160459), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 286123, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (286123/286123), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (70333/70333), done.
remote: Total 286123 (delta 209006), reused 285449 (delta 208740), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (286123/286123), 33.61 MiB | 648.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (209006/209006), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 167187, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (167187/167187), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42503/42503), done.
remote: Total 167187 (delta 120446), reused 167004 (delta 120410), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (167187/167187), 17.62 MiB | 965.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (120446/120446), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 171590, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (171590/171590), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43528/43528), done.
remote: Total 171590 (delta 123738), reused 171423 (delta 123710), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (171590/171590), 18.23 MiB | 608.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (123738/123738), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 302328, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (302328/302328), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (74668/74668), done.
remote: Total 302328 (delta 220842), reused 301113 (delta 220160), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (302328/302328), 35.66 MiB | 690.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (220842/220842), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 310919, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (310919/310919), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76888/76888), done.
remote: Total 310919 (delta 227244), reused 309478 (delta 226330), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (310919/310919), 36.72 MiB | 870.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (227244/227244), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 171619, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (171619/171619), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43538/43538), done.
remote: Total 171619 (delta 123763), reused 171446 (delta 123729), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (171619/171619), 18.24 MiB | 649.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (123763/123763), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 307061, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (307061/307061), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (75982/75982), done.
remote: Total 307061 (delta 224297), reused 305698 (delta 223483), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (307061/307061), 36.23 MiB | 705.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (224297/224297), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 251699, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (251699/251699), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62225/62225), done.
remote: Total 251699 (delta 183391), reused 251335 (delta 183301), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (251699/251699), 29.45 MiB | 676.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (183391/183391), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 201003, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (201003/201003), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50452/50452), done.
remote: Total 201003 (delta 145560), reused 200770 (delta 145538), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (201003/201003), 22.65 MiB | 748.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (145560/145560), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 319612, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (319612/319612), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (79022/79022), done.
remote: Total 319612 (delta 233963), reused 317889 (delta 232760), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (319612/319612), 37.60 MiB | 719.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (233963/233963), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 254495, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (254495/254495), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (63083/63083), done.
remote: Total 254495 (delta 185280), reused 253962 (delta 185173), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (254495/254495), 29.84 MiB | 847.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (185280/185280), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 293524, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (293524/293524), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (72321/72321), done.
remote: Total 293524 (delta 214351), reused 292565 (delta 213889), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (293524/293524), 34.55 MiB | 757.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (214351/214351), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 168718, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (168718/168718), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42870/42870), done.
remote: Total 168718 (delta 121588), reused 168529 (delta 121547), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (168718/168718), 17.85 MiB | 719.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (121588/121588), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 288667, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (288667/288667), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71211/71211), done.
remote: Total 288667 (delta 210575), reused 287859 (delta 210275), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (288667/288667), 34.00 MiB | 786.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (210575/210575), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 260527, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (260527/260527), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (64360/64360), done.
remote: Total 260527 (delta 189932), reused 259919 (delta 189775), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (260527/260527), 30.49 MiB | 828.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (189932/189932), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 289005, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (289005/289005), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71290/71290), done.
remote: Total 289005 (delta 210856), reused 288186 (delta 210532), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (289005/289005), 34.03 MiB | 688.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (210856/210856), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 296686, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (296686/296686), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73240/73240), done.
remote: Total 296686 (delta 216603), reused 295570 (delta 216018), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (296686/296686), 34.98 MiB | 962.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (216603/216603), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 246397, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (246397/246397), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60828/60828), done.
remote: Total 246397 (delta 179620), reused 245952 (delta 179503), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (246397/246397), 28.78 MiB | 722.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (179620/179620), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 170800, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (170800/170800), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43334/43334), done.
remote: Total 170800 (delta 123148), reused 170633 (delta 123124), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (170800/170800), 18.14 MiB | 710.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (123148/123148), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 297907, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (297907/297907), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73486/73486), done.
remote: Total 297907 (delta 217567), reused 296774 (delta 216973), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (297907/297907), 35.09 MiB | 804.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (217567/217567), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 309510, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (309510/309510), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76587/76587), done.
remote: Total 309510 (delta 226091), reused 308154 (delta 225275), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (309510/309510), 36.55 MiB | 908.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (226091/226091), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 278866, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (278866/278866), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (68501/68501), done.
remote: Total 278866 (delta 203746), reused 278318 (delta 203596), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (278866/278866), 32.64 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (203746/203746), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 291462, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (291462/291462), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71900/71900), done.
remote: Total 291462 (delta 212738), reused 290542 (delta 212308), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (291462/291462), 34.31 MiB | 865.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (212738/212738), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 167199, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (167199/167199), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42510/42510), done.
remote: Total 167199 (delta 120453), reused 167013 (delta 120415), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (167199/167199), 17.62 MiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (120453/120453), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 281169, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (281169/281169), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (69130/69130), done.
remote: Total 281169 (delta 205282), reused 280594 (delta 205128), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (281169/281169), 32.95 MiB | 946.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (205282/205282), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 298606, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (298606/298606), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73703/73703), done.
remote: Total 298606 (delta 218048), reused 297478 (delta 217451), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (298606/298606), 35.19 MiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (218048/218048), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 286443, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (286443/286443), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (70409/70409), done.
remote: Total 286443 (delta 209271), reused 285747 (delta 208984), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (286443/286443), 33.66 MiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (209271/209271), done.
...
```

It has been running like that for an hour now. My machine is relatively new and the network connection is reasonable. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried deleting and re-cloning the repository?

Comment: It seems your `git` or `git-log` is replaced by another executable, maybe a script or a function. The log looks like the output of `git fetch`. Did you define any alias or function or script that happens to overwrite the original `git` or `git log`? Try `which git` and `which git-log`. And check `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `which git` returns `/usr/bin/git`. I don't have a `git-log`.

Comment: I haven't tried deleting and re-cloning. I am trying to avoid doing that, because I have some local branches that I would like to preserve.

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/git log`. And `bash --debugger; declare -F git`. `type git` could also give a hint if `git` is overwritten.

Comment: I am thinking that git is auto-garbage collecting, which is fine with me, if only it'll finish within a reasonable time span.

Comment: @ElpieKay I suspect the initial clone was performed with `--filter=blob:none` (and may be `tree:0`) and now `git log` fetches trees and blobs.

Comment: @phd I have not tried partial clone yet. It's a bit odd that `git log` fetches data. To my understanding, `git log` is a local action. But for git lfs repository, `git checkout`, another local action, also fetches data. I think your guess makes sense.

Comment: @ElpieKay After partial clone GIt fetches filtered data when touching commits. On `git checkout` for sure, on `git diff` most probably, not sure about `git log` — I also don't have enough experience with partial clones. `git log -p` touches commits so it surely must fetch.